# How to tell if HTML element is tracked by virtual DOM

Tags: html, reactjs

I have a react application inside of an MVC shell with  many controls.

How can I set up a global click listener on the document and then check if the event.target is an element that originated inside my react application or not?

I would like to avoid applying any boilerplate (tags, etc) to my React components or elements inside my components.

Comment: Do you have a single React root?

Comment: Yes we have a single react root. As soon as I read your comment it reminded me of something that I read in the docs. Currently looking at the is-react npm package but would like to avoid the dependency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that you have a single React container element and you can access it, I'd do something like this:

```
document.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    const target = event.target;
    // root is the element which was used in ReactDOM.render(<App />, root)
    // replace document.getElementById('root') with whatever works in your case
    const root = document.getElementById('root')

    const targetInReact = root.contains(target);

});
```

Note: this won't work for elements rendered using [portals](https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html) outside parent element hierarchy.